# Submenu needs to be full width of browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have a menu that displays a horizontal submenu when the parent menu is clicked. I need the horizontal sub menu to be full width of the browser window. I have managed to nearly achieve this as you can see [here](http://foley13.webfactional.com/sotl/#) but the sub menu now allows you scrolls horizontal which looks bad. This is the css that is creating the full width submenu.

```
ul.dropdown {
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  margin-top: 0;
  background: #333;
  width: 100vw;
  min-width: 100vw;
  padding: 0;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 -9999px; padding: 0 9999px; /* this gets the full width of the sub menu */
  box-sizing: content-box; /* this prevents the li from behaving badly */
```

Is there anyway of preventing the large horizontal scroll yet still have the submenu full width of the browser window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a super pretty solution but the absolutely easiest would be to just set `overflow-x: hidden;` on the body